# How to find sample space (all possible outcomes), if coin is tossed n times

Tags: recursion, probability

Let a list: `lst=["head","tail"]`

The sample space, if coin tossed 2 times will be:

```
["H","H"]
["H","T"]
["T","H"]
["T","T"]
```

But how to get the sample space if coin tossed n number of times?

In my opinion, recursion can do the task, but I am unable to implement the logic here.

I can understand python and C.

```
# for coin tossed 2 times:

lst = ['h','t']

for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        print(f"[{lst[i]}, {lst[j]}]")
```

OUTPUT:

```
[h, h]
[h, t]
[t, h]
[t, t]
```

Comment: I think you want the [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product): `list(itertools.product("ht", repeat=2))`. Already answered in [Have python program print out all combinations of coin flips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335459/have-python-program-print-out-all-combinations-of-coin-flips/40335512#40335512), although this is a better-asked question.

Comment: To get all of the possible outcomes of tossing a coin *n* times, enumerate all integers from 0 to (2^n)-1 in binary.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right that recursion can be a good way to solve this problem. You'll want to create a recursive function that keeps track of the current combination of coin tosses and calls itself with one fewer toss until the number of tosses reaches zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create an array with the combinations for n consecutive coint tosses you don't really need recursion.

You start off with an array of `["H", "T"]` and update this every time `n` is larger than 1. The update doubles the number of elements adding heads to the first lot and tails to the second.

One down to 1 your array has all the combinations. `n=0` needs to be handles specifically if you want to support it.

Thus for 2 coins it iterates once with the result `["HH", "TH", "HT", "TT]`.

Another way to look at anything like this is that you have a number where the radix is the number of symbols. In this case it is always 2, which is binary, so displaying the numbers in binary should give you the combinations and making that a string is just converting from number to new symbols for `0` and `1`. If you have n coins the combinations are `[,(2^n)-1]` and eg. 3 coins is zero to 7 and binary 0 is heads and binary 1 is tails:

```
000 HHH
001 HHT
010 HTH
..
111 TTT
```

Both of these can be implemented with using recursion since everything iterative can be made recursive.

Answer (score 0):

For each coin that will be flipped, there exists two possibilities for each possibility of the *remaining* coins.

```js
function *outcomes(n) {
  if (n < 0) return
  if (n == 0) return yield ""
  for (const outcome of outcomes(n - 1)) {
    yield "H" + outcome
    yield "T" + outcome
  }
}

console.log(Array.from(outcomes(3)))
```

And here's the non-lazy form that always returns the full array -

```js
function outcomes(n) {
  if (n < 0) return []
  if (n == 0) return [""]
  return outcomes(n - 1).flatMap(outcome => [
    "H" + outcome,
    "T" + outcome,
  ])
}

console.log(outcomes(3))
```

I represent the outcomes using a string for simplicity of code, but you could swap it out for an array if that's what you need. Here's the output -

```js
[
  "HHH",
  "THH",
  "HTH",
  "TTH",
  "HHT",
  "THT",
  "HTT",
  "TTT"
]
```